# i am able cache data using cacheManager on startup of application but not for those api which is not having argument in soringboot application

Tags: caching

```
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        cachLookType();
    }

    private void cachLookType() {
        List<Lookups> lks = ld.getAll();
        cacheManager.getCache("lookup").put("root.methodName", lks);
        }
    }
```

code is for caching data on startup of application only for no argument API, I want to how we can use no argument Api.

```
    @Cacheable(value = "lookup", key = "#root.methodName")
    public List<Lookups> getLookup() {
        List<Lookups> lks = ld.getAll();
        return lks;
    }
```